# PHP DateTime will not allow a date format

Tags: php, datetime, date, php-5.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strtotime failing on mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133703/strtotime-failing-on-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm)

I have a date coming in like shown below but the DateTime function will not allow it:

```
            $start = new DateTime('13/10/2012');
            echo $start->format("Y-m-d");
```

It allows all other methods, even using '10/13/2012' but I can't change it because that's the format i'm receiving the date in.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try, createFromFormat() ?

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '13/10/2012');
```

Answer (score 1):

try DateTime::createFromFormat like

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '13/10/2012');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it only accepts dates in specific formats, one of them is "american month, day, year", which will obviously fail if you provide 13 as the month.

I always try to avoid working with dates in ambiguous formats. Mostly using "2012-10-13" within the code, and "13 Oct, 2012" for user-facing dates. Both can be parsed reliably by any date formatting API I've got experience with.

But when forced to work with an ambiguous format, I parse it manually instead of relying on PHP's built in API, since I fully understand what it's going to do. For example:

```
list($day, $month, $year) = preg_split('/[^0-9]+/', '13/10/2012');
$start = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
```